# certificate unknown error new APNS prod certificate not working

Tags: ios, certificate

My Prod APNS certificate got expired a couple of days back. I somehow lost my private keys. So I generated a new CSR, new Distribution certificate and provisioning profile. I changed the .p12 file on my Push Server. Now when I try to send a notification to the app (Downloaded from the App Store), I get a **certificate unknown** error. I am using **Java notnoop-apns** library to send push notifications.

What may be the reason for this?

Comment: Please check for your bundle id and all the details that you had previously is same in this one also. Also check the apns keys.

Comment: bundle id's are the same

Comment: Something is surely missing!!! Weird... May be device not registered or any step you are missing ...

Comment: i don't know. i did everything else. i had a question though: if i change my CSR and regenerate all certificates again, do i need to push again to app store?

Comment: i regenerated the dev certificates again as well. i am getting a registration ID from APNS. with the new certificate, i am not getting any error, but the notification is also not coming to my device

Comment: Check in your plist if there is development set then check your keys and all.